# How to convert a year to date in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with year data in a year datatype field, now I want to insert new data with date data and I want to convert the year from the old data to date with default month and day 1.1.YearFromOldData.
I'm looking for something like the function STR_TO_DATE but for the datatype year NOT VARCHAR NOT VARCHAR and I fail to find it. How would I do this?

I want to do this

SELECT  YEAR_TO_DATE(myYearField, '%1/%1/%Y')
FROM    myTable

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is it more clear now @GordonLinoff ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a `varchar` field named `year_dt` with old years, use the following query to get a date with default day and month

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(table.year_dt, '-01-01')) as 'date' FROM table
```

this will return date in default format i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Sorry my phrasing was unclear the year is stored in the datatype year. does your method still work with that information?

Comment: yes it should work if its a `year` field too, you should try it

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first day of the year, I think the easiest way is with `makedate()`:

```
select makedate(year, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamp to insert to the database using

```
timestamp = (year - 1970) / 31557600
```

Answer (score 0):

`STR_TO_DATE()` is exactly what you need.  Try this if you have four-digit years, in a string, an integer, or a `YEAR` column. It works for them all.

```
select str_to_date(CONCAT(year_column,'-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you have two-digit years try this (lower case %y)

```
select str_to_date(CONCAT(year_column,'-01-01'), '%y-%m-%d')
```

This is cool because you can do all sorts of date arithmetic: for example

```
select str_to_date(CONCAT(year_column,'-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
       + INTERVAL 1 QUARTER
       - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

will give you the last day of the first quarter of your year.

Comment: Sorry my phrasing was unclear the year is stored in the datatype year. does your method still work with that information?

Comment: Yes. Please see my edit.  If you haven't found http://sqlfiddle.com/ you should check it out.